# Add counts to dict values

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

```
arr = [1,1,3,2,2,4]
d={i:[] for i in range(max(arr)+1)}

for i in arr:
    if i in d.keys():
        d[i] += 1
```

Am trying to get a result of {0:0, 1:2, 2:2, 3:1, 4:1} but get getting 
    TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable 
    Can any kind soul point to me what's the error? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna do this:

```
arr = [1,1,3,2,2,4]
d = {i:0 for i in range(max(arr)+1)}

for i in arr:
    if i in d.keys():
        d[i] += 1
```

Or try more efficient way (you won't find keys which are not in array):

```
from collections import Counter

arr = [1,1,3,2,2,4]
d = Counter(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the part of the list comprehension to create 0 for each number until the max number instead of an empty list

```
arr = [1,1,3,2,2,4]

d={i:0 for i in range(max(arr) + 1)}

for i in arr:
  if i in d.keys():
     d[i] += 1
print(d)
```

Or to use dictionary comprehension with the range of max number in `arr` list and count of the list.

```
{v: arr.count(v) for v in range(max(arr) + 1)}
```

Output

```
{0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 1}
```